# HtmlUnit and saving page as PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, reporting, htmlunit, headless-browser

In the Java EE environment, I want to load an `XML` and `XSL` file, render the output to a browser window, and save the rendered page as PDF.

I would like to do it all programmatically.  I was looking at HtmlUnit to use as a headless browser.  That part seems to work, but does HtmlUnit have any API to invoke a "print" function or similar function to persisted the rendered output?  I was thinking of some way to link it in with iText.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend trying out [flying-saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) which in this case basically is a CSS/XHTML enabled iText wrapper.

I wrote a simple example below. Don't forget the necessary dependencies for HtmlUnit and flying-saucer.

```
//Set up a new WebClient using your favourite settings
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

//Fetch page
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("url-to-target.resource");

//Set PDF target output file
String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

//Set up flying-saucer IText based renderer 
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

//Create PDF
renderer.setDocumentFromString(page.asXml();
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);

os.close();
```

Comment: If I use flying saucer for generating PDF and it uses iText, then do i need a commercial license for iText in this case?

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing reporting in Java i highly recommend you to use [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/), it's relatively easy to use, you can design the report graphically and it can take XML as input and give you a report in many formats (including PDF).